Struggling with relative imports. Help me confirm that my understanding of "attempted relative import beyond top-level package" error is correct
In my folder named project, this is my directory structure.
.
├── folder_1
│   ├── folder_3
│   │   ├── module_3.py
│   │   └── module_4.py
│   └── module_1.py
├── folder_2
│   └── module_2.py
└── script.py

I am trying to do relative imports inside module_3.py
# module_3.py
print("Code is currently in module_3.py file")
print("\n File name of module_3.py :",__name__)

from . import module_4
from .. import module_1
from ...folder_2 import module_2


When I do python3 -m project.folder_1.folder_3.module_3, it runs successfully.

When I run python3 -m folder_1.folder_3.module_3, I am getting below error:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/remote/project/folder_1/folder_3/module_3.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ...folder_2 import module_2
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

What I know is that relative imports works inside packages only.
QUESTION - Is my understanding correct that giving project in command helps python understand that project is also a package, otherwise it considers only folder_1 a package and cannot find folder_2 even if it is at the same level as folder_1 because it does not recognize its parent folder project directory as a package since I am running the command excluding project word from it.
Does this mean it is always better to run your program with the topmost parent folder name in your command hence telling python the top most package.
If not so, what is the reason it cannot traverse folder_2 which is a sibling directory at the same level as folder_1

Does this answer your question? Relative imports for the billionth time

I did refer to and read this question in detail before posting. I feel my understanding is correct, I need someone to confirm the same.

Are you running the commands from the same folder (project)?

Running python3 -m project.folder_1.folder_3.module_3 from one folder above project and running python3 -m folder_1.folder_3.module_3 from project

Do you have the __init__ files in these folders as well?

You are getting the error cause relative imports work for a fixed package structure. When you write from ...folder_2 import module_2 you tell python go to parent of parent of this package there you will find folder_2 package. If you run from inside the project dir then python has to go one level up from the current top level package hence the error. So run python3 -m project.folder_1.folder_3.module_3 from the parent of project. You could run python3 -m folder_1.folder_3.module_3 from inside the project folder but then you should change the import to from folder_2 import module_2.

Running python3 - m folder_1.folder_3.module_3 from inside the project folder with from ..folder_2 import module_2 gives from ..folder_2 import module_2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_1.folder_2'

correction - python3 -m folder_1.folder_3.module_3 i.e no space between dash and m

Yep you are right - I meant from folder_2 import module_2 (an absolute import, as python adds the cwd in sys.path and all its packages become top level as opposed to cwd being project where those packages are under project.* namespace)

Right. I know absolute import would have worked there. My question was that for Python to consider a directory as a package, I also need to include it in my command after -m i.e. even though folder_2 is at the same level as folder_1, folder_2 is not considered as a package when we run python3 -m folder_1.folder_3.module_3. Only the directories inside folder_1 is a package and it doesn't matter for a sibling directory like folder_2 unless the parent of folder_2 i.e. project is also in -m

When cwd == project all package directories inside project are packages and in fact top level  packages. Hence when you write from ...folder_2 import ... inside folder_1.folder_3.module_3 you try to go in the containing package of folder_1 - but this is a top level package. When your cwd is the parent dir of project, then the top level package is project. In short, python adds all packages in the cwd as top level packages - so project in one case and folder_1 and folder_2 in the other are your top level packages
